# I stopped to smoke

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

I stopped to smoke.

I know that in the sentence 'Stop' is used as an intransitive verb.
But what if it is a transitive verb in that?

I think It would mean 'Upon thinking to smoke a cigarette, I stopped the thinking'.

And 'Stop' could be a transitive verb in the sentence on a particular situation?

Comment: "_I stopped to smoke_" is very different from "_I stopped smoking_".

Comment: "I stopped (in place) to have a smoke." (intransitive) vs. "I stopped the smoke from filling up the room by opening a window" (transitive).  Of course there's always "I stopped you from smoking"